# Chrome extension onMessage listener not firing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a rather complicated Chrome extension that has been working perfectly for a long time, but when Ubuntu automatically updated Chromium browser from 48.0.xxx to Version 49.0.2623.87 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), then (it seems) my extension script fails to work after reboot.

In `background.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(id, {text: "abc"});
```

In `contentscript.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("Processing message....");
        // ... rest of code
    });
```

This used to work, but now is not working.  I do not even see the "Processing message...." printed in the console.

Also, I got some additional strange behavior, but that might not be related to the problem:

At first, my content script failed to load, complaining about an icon in `manifest.json`.  I specified the icon size ("16") and the script is able to load.  But that is strange because the manifest used to work without any glitch.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of failure.  The new Chrome requires to put "tabs" in the permission in `manifest.json`, for example:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://localhost/",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "contextMenus"
],
```

This allows

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "http://example.com/"} ,...)；
```

to work.  In my script, the lack of permission caused this to return rubbish, and the message was not sent correctly.

Chrome's behavior changed during the update.  Before that, the "tabs" permission requirement was not strictly enforced.